# UIButton not rendering correctly in iOS6 when calling renderInContext on CALayer

Tags: iphone, ios, uibutton, ios6, cgcontext

I'm having this issue that seems to only be occuring in iOS 6. I am calling renderInContext on a view's layer. This view is fairly simple. It has a few UIButtons. The UIImage I get back from the following code seems to be corrupted. The UIButtons don't seem to be drawing correctly.

```
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(self.view.bounds.size, self.view.opaque, 0.0);
    [self.view.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
    UIImage *viewSnapShot = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

This code produces a bitmap that looks like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/iTspJ.jpg

When I run the app in the iPhone 5.1 simulator this problem doesn't seem to be occurring. I'm starting to wonder if it's just a bug in iOS 6.

Anyone run into a similar issue?

Comment: Got the same problem. See here: http://i.imgur.com/WXsa9.png

Comment: Do you see this on your devices as well? To me it seems, that this is only happening in the simulator.